# Links not working

Tags: html, hyperlink

For some reason, my links don't seem to be working to other pages within my site.

For example, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gZec5/).

Here is a snippet of the html:

```
<li><a href="blinds.html">Product List</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="blinds.html#venetian">Venetian Blinds</a></li>
    <li><a href="blinds.html#roller">Roller Blinds</a></li>
    <li><a href="blinds.html#roman">Roman Blinds</a></li>
    <li><a href="blinds.html#vertical">Vertical Blinds</a></li>
    <li><a href="blinds.html#honeycomb">Honeycomb Blinds</a></li>
```

To see it in action, check out [www.everythingblinds.com.au/index_NOTLIVE.html](http://www.everythingblinds.com.au/index_NOTLIVE.html) (I know I shouldn't link to my site, but I don't know how else to demonstrate this issue fully without showing the actual website, where all the pages are)

All the pages that I link to have been created, and should as far as I can see, load when links are clicked. Neither the top nav or the bottom nav seem to be working.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a piece of script: `$('a').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
     });
    
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
});
```

to:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
});
```